# Shortcut to navigate between highlighted usages

Tags: intellij-idea

According to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/highlighting-usages.html) page navigating between highlighted usages:

[image: highlighted usage]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](https://www.jetbrains.com/img/webhelp/highlightUsages.png))</sub>

can be done using *<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> keyboard shortcuts, to navigate to the next and previous usages respectively.*

However these shortcuts are by default used to navigate between search occurences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), not highlighted usages, and indeed this is how they work. Is there any other way to navigate between highlighted usages using keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> work just fine here. Highlighted usages do not differ from search occurrences in this context.

Comment: Open `java.lang.String` class. First Search (*Ctrl+F*) for `value` - *F3* will navigate between plenty of **text** occurrences in JavaDocs, etc. OK. Now click/highlight on `offset` **field**. A lot of highlighted usages will appear, but *F3* still navigates between `value` search occurrences, not between highlighted `offset` field usages. Do you get my point?

Comment: I get your point. Looks like it's not possible to use both features at the same time, you need to remove search occurrences highlighting before navigating between usages. Feel free to submit a request to IDEA issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I filled [IDEA-70523](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-70523) issue.

Answer (score 8):

Install the [Identifier Highlighter](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1236) plugin.

It's a must have plugin for IntelliJ, and is always the very first thing I do to a fresh IDEA installation. I can't understand why this hasn't become part of core IntelliJ yet.

Comment: There is now an [IdentifierHighlighter Reloaded](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?&id=6318) plugin that works with the new built-in highlighting. It's really just a one-key shortcut for Clear Highlights + Highlight Usages + Next/Prev Highlight, but it works.

Comment: This plug just activates an in-file search for the string, not occurrences of the variable.

Answer (score 5):

I've found on mac that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> works for this purpose well. It actually selects the occurrence for you, which is fine for me. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> for the previous occurrence.

On Windows/Linus this should be <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> respectively.

Comment: Great to know the built in solution.. better than having to add & learn one more plugin. Worked for me on Mavericks. Thanks!

Comment: This will select any matching string, whereas the post is about matching occurrences of a variable.

Answer (score 2):

For linux key mapping setup in IDEA go to next occurrence are <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>.
<kbd>Alt+J</kbd> is for selection for next occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> navigates to the next and previous usages of a highlighted variable in IntelliJ.

I use this functionality of navigating to the next usage of a variable in a file by hot in Visual Studio all the time (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>) and was looking for the equivalent in IntelliJ