# IntelliJ navigate to next and previous highlighted variable

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ 10.5 I have "Highlight usages of element at caret" enabled. When a variable/method/etc is selected, is there a way to move to the next and previous occurrence? I'm looking for the equivalent of [Control-K in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019818/eclipse-navigate-to-next-previous-marked-occurrence).

**Edit**: [Shortcut to navigate between highlighted usages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198687) simply moves to the next **text** occurrence, which is different than moving to the next occurrence of the variable/method/etc. If I have the variable `foo` selected, I want to navigate to the next occurrence of `foo` and not any piece of text called "foo" (including "foo" in comments, method names, etc).

Also, pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> seems to be buggy. When I press <kbd>F3</kbd>, it sometimes searches using the previous searched text and **not** the currently highlighted text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortcut to navigate between highlighted usages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198687/shortcut-to-navigate-between-highlighted-usages)

Comment: About your edit: please read carefully the thread and comments you are quoting: *CrazyCoder* admits F3 is not working as expected, hence I created [IDEA-70523](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-70523)

Comment: Yup, my question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's not currently possible, see my question: [Shortcut to navigate between highlighted usages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198687/shortcut-to-navigate-between-highlighted-usages).

I even created an issue [IDEA-70523](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-70523) addressing this feature, please vote for it if you can't live without it like me :-).

Comment: It's marked as fixed, and indeed, F3 / shift F3 work now in the context of ctrl+shift-F7 highlighting

Comment: [IDEA-59638](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59638) appears to be the current issue for this, as the previous one was misunderstood and closed.

Comment: Nowadays this action is called 'Find Next / Move to Next occurrence'

Comment: Rider still have this problem. Current issue is [RIDER-15896](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-15896/)

Answer (score 44):

- F3 or shift+F3
- ctrl+c, ctrl+f, enter or up and down arrows
- ctrl+alt+F7

Added this in case people don't look at your edit.

Comment: ctrl+alt+F7 was what I was looking for.

Comment: for android studio: cmd + shift + F7, then cmd + G / cmd + shift + G

Comment: Note that if you have *already used* `F3`, selecting yet another word via Caret somewhere in word + `Ctrl + W`, + `F3`(to search) will not work. You need to `Ctrl + W`, + `Ctrl + F3` first( to put the new selected word in the search buffer), then `F3` or `Shift F3`.

Answer (score 12):

Install [Identifier Highlighter Reloaded](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/6318-identifier-highlighter-reloaded) and use Alt + Shift + Up/Down (can be redefined in Keymap settings) :)

After you give it a shot and notice the 'hey, the highlight stays there after I move my cursor out of it' annoyance, consider upvoting [this issue](https://github.com/OlegYch/ih-reloaded/issues/3) :)

Comment: THIS is what I've been looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In the Mac OS, you can navigate to next highlighted usage by press `control` + `option` + `up/down arrow`.

Comment: Thanks for this! I found is via the reverse lookup of what you suggested in the KeyMap preferences. It is buried in the Edit menu. How the developers at IntelliJ consider this an "Edit" function and not "Navigate" is beyond me.

Answer (score 4):

I found something thay may more suite your needs : alt + mouse-wheel up/down.
It goes to previous / next occurrence of identifier under caret.

Shortcut name is "Go to next highlighted element usage".

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Vote this request up for make them implement the feature.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59638

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the following:

1. Highlight the word
2. Cmd + F (it will highlight all the matches in file)
3. Cmd + G (next match)
4. Cmd + Shift + G (previous match)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any of IntelliJ's native options for Find Next/Previous to behave like in Eclipse. `Find Word at Caret` comes close, but it only allows you to slurp and find the next word, not previous.

`Identifier Highlighter Reloaded` also does not behave like Eclipse.

I wrote an IntelliJ plugin to reproduce the exact behavior as in Eclipse. You can find it here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10635-quick-find-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Look for next occurrence @ Keymap

[image: Key mappings: next occurrence]

`^G` = "select" the variable that you want to search for

`[shift]⌘G` = [previous]next occurrence of selected variable

All credits to @Igor Wojda for his comment in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

(AFAIK, limiting search scope to only variable/method is not possible)

For text based match and quick jump:

1. Simply place the cursor over the desired word to be searched
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
3. For further down/up search, simply use
   <kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>Shift+F3</kbd> respectively

Answer (score 0):

in Intellij shortcut for this action, it's not defined.
but you can define it like this:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
- search `" highlighted usage"`
- then you can set a shortcut for that.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> navigates to the next and previous usages of a highlighted variable in IntelliJ.

I use this functionality of navigating to the next usage of a variable in a file by hot in Visual Studio all the time (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>) and was looking for the equivalent in IntelliJ