# eclipse ctrl+k equivalent shortcut in IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In *Eclipse*, if the cursor is over a word and you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> you will jump to the next occurrence of that word in the file.

Is there a similar shortcut in *IntelliJ*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ navigate to next and previous highlighted variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281623/intellij-navigate-to-next-and-previous-highlighted-variable)

Answer (score 50):

**Find word at caret**, default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, can be changed in `File` | `Settings` | `Keymap`:

[image: Find word at caret]

Comment: This sort of works, but it doesn't wrap and it doesn't carry over to the next file. In eclipse its nicer: once you hit ctrl-K it caches the text, so even if you switch to another file when you hit ctrl-K again, it finds the occurrence there (and it wraps).
Not that your answer is wrong, just would be nice if intellij would have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 18):

You will need 2 Steps to archive a similar behavior:

Step 1:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to start a search for the current selectet text (if no text is selected then the whole word will be taken).

Step 2:

Press <kbd>F3</kbd> to jump to **next** occurrence or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to jump to the **previous**.

This approach will even continue the search for the text if you switch to another file. Just press <kbd>F3</kbd> and you will jump to the next occurrence in the other file.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> works for me in *Android Studio / IntelliJ*, in eclipse we were using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

I think *Android Studio/IntelliJ* doesn't play that well, for me, I changed *Android Studio Keymap* to *Eclipse* as I used to ([My collection tips](http://ask.osify.com/qa/812)) and to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, I press search the string first:

- Select the text we want to search
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Then can use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in any file we are on

That's what I'm doing, hope can help someone with that.

Comment: I'm using this solution as well but it's very painful due I need to press Ctrl+F, Enter to update the cache of the search to every new "text" that I want to search for. 
Someone knows how to find the next reference of a selected string without use the search command? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using macros:

- Edit -> Macros -> Start Macro Recording
- Edit -> Find -> Find Word at Caret
- Edit -> Find -> Find Next/ Move to Next Occurrence
- Edit -> Macros -> Stop Macro Recording
- Give some name for the macro, e.g. "simulate Eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>"
- File -> Settings -> Keymap -> Find the macro "simulate eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>" -> bind hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

The same can be done for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (use Find Previous/ Move to Previous Occurrence).

Answer (score 2):

#### Keymap : Mac OS X 10.5+

- To start / add to your discrete multiple selection : <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
- To skip the current selection and move to the next : <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

Refer:
[Does IntelliJ have a `Ctrl` + `K`,`Ctrl` + `D` Sublime equivalent? How do I skip a match when using Alt+J for multiple selections in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049740/does-intellij-have-a-ctrl-k-ctrl-d-sublime-equivalent-how-do-i-skip)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options like below in : Settings -> Keymap -> Main menu -> Find

- Find Next / Move to Next Occurrence
- Find Previous/ Move to Previous Occurrence

For me, this didn't work at the start because GIT push shortcut was using the same keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>). All is good after changing the conflicting GIT shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need to first do Ctrl+F on the selected word, now this gets cached then you can use the Ctrl+L and ctrl+shitf+L for going down and up respectively. This is already present. its just that instead of ctrl+K you got use ctrl+L. small change same effect

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ, if the cursor is over a word and you press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> you will jump to the next occurrence of that word in the file. Similarly, you press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> you will jump to the previous occurrence of that word in the file