# Search in intellij vs eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I recently moved to intellij-idea-12 from eclipse.

In eclipse if select a text and click 'ctrl+k' or 'ctrl+shift+k', it takes me to next/previous search text within the file.

In intellij if i do select text and click 'ctrl+l' or 'ctrl+shift+l' it is not taking me to the search text.

In intellij first i have to do 'ctrl+f', then only 'ctrl+l' or 'ctrl+shift+l' are working.

Is there any setting to make it work like eclipse searching.

Note: I am not talking about changing keymap in intellij.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856947/eclipse-ctrlk-equivalent-shortcut-in-intellij

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ navigate to next and previous highlighted variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281623/intellij-navigate-to-next-and-previous-highlighted-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caret on the word you want to search for (or with the text highlighted), press `CTRL+F3`. After that, you can just press `F3` to find the next occurrence and `SHIFT+F3` to find the previous occurrence.

Note that I am still using version 11.1.5

Comment: Without pressing ctrl+f3, i want search using by just selecting the text and pressing f3/shift+f3... It is possible in eclipse

Comment: @Shanmukhan If you don't like pressing CTRL, you can remap the "Find Word at Caret" option to just F3 and then you would only need to press F3 and SHIFT+F3

Comment: Now that was useful!

Answer (score 1):

By default it's ALT+J to move down and shift+ALT+J to move up.