# How to do Ctrl+K of Eclipse in InteliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I recently migrated from eclipse to IntelliJ just for using android studio.

I am not able to find the shortcut for basic find feature

Ctrl + K / Ctrl + Shift + K - Highlight next/previous occurrence of selected text.

Of course I did search and study.
[PDF](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) gave lot of usefully shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found is using eclipse keymap in intelliJ

press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

which will pop up a search box.
Search for eclipse.
Click on first result.
Modify the default keymap to eclipse.

Almost all the shortcuts in eclipse should be back.
You have to search the term using ctrl+f and then do ctrl+k

Answer (score 1):

Use CTRL+SHIFT+A to search for actions. If shortcuts are available, they are displayed next to the action name in this search-result window. This way allows you to learn IDEA easier and probably faster.

If you want to assign a shortcut for an action (CTRL+SHIFT+A) search for "keymap" (in the Settings section) - this will open the Settings window and guide you to the keymap section. There you can search for actions and assign shortcuts and secondary shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Per this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6281772/248847)'s answer, <kbd>F3</kbd> / <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> seems to work in the context of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>(or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) highlighting.  Consider giving credit to the orignal answerer of that post, if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

the 'shortcuttranslator' plugin adds a simple dialog box that lets you explore the relationships between different keymaps, e.g. the standard eclipse keymap and the default idea keymap.  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6827?pr=